# How do I properly load my lazily associated entities (without making them eagerly loaded)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I'm building a WAR using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JPA 2.0, and replying to JBoss 7.1.1.Final.  I have this entity with a couple of lazy associations …

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-strategy", strategy = "uuid.hex")
@Entity
@Table(name = "cb_contract",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"OPPORTUNITY_ID","PRODUCT_ID"})}
)
public class Contract implements Serializable {

    …
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Product.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Product product;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Organization.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Organization org;
```

I load these entities from one transactional method …

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ContractServiceImpl implements ContractService
...

public List<Contract> findContractByOppId(final String oppId)
{
    final Contract contract = new Contract();
    contract.setOpportunityId(oppId);
    return m_contractDao.find(contract);
}   // findContractByOppId
```

and then try to save them in another @Transactional method (this private method is called from the @Transactional public method):

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{
...
private void saveUserContracts(final User user, final Set<Contract> contracts)
{
    if (contracts != null)
    {
        for (final Contract contract : contracts)
        {
            contract.getOrg();
            contract.getProduct();

            final UserContract userContract = new UserContract();
            userContract.setContract(contract);
            userContract.setUser(user);
            userContractDao.save(userContract);
        }   // for
    }   // if
}   // saveUserContracts
```

However, upon trying to save them, I get the exception below.  How do I get the lazy entities to load (preferably using JPA as opposed to a Hibernate-specific method)?

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization_$$_javassist_10.hashCode(Organization_$$_javassist_10.java)
    at org.mainco.subco.ecom.domain.Contract.hashCode(Contract.java:134)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:372)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:200)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:100)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.test.service.UserServiceTest.testAddUser(UserServiceTest.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Hard to tell since you're not showing all the methods involved. From where is `saveUserContracts` called? In which class are those methods? In which class is `findContractByOppId`? What are the `@Transactional` annotations exactly (i.e. any attributes)?

Comment: I cannot the any of the code you posted in the stacktrace, but a line `at org.mainco.subco.user.test.service.UserServiceTest.testAddUser(UserServiceTest.java:116)` so it seems this error happens when running a unit test. Any chance the test is not configured to set up the transactional magic? Why do you think the error happens when saving the entities?

Comment: @MarcelStör, I added some class level code to illustrate that the methods shown are from two different Spring service classes.  I'm using the "org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional" annotations without any attributes.  Why would any of that influence how I can load lazy attributes in my domain object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided I think there are at least three things wrong (correct me if my interpretation doesn't match with reality):

- `Contract#hashCode()` seems to depend on properties that are lazily loaded. Don't do that, `hashCode` is such a fundamental method it needs to work in every context i.e. even if the entity is not attached to a session.
- You seem to be doing something like this: class X calls transactional service A, gets results and passes them to another transactional service B. What happens is that once A completes all entities are *detached* i.e. they are no longer attached to a persistence session which means you cannot lazily load members. Even inside B, where you have a session, those entities do not automatically get re-attached. Essentially that's the reason for the exception.
- `UserServiceTest` may or may not have set up transaction support properly, really can't tell.

What you can do is to ensure that X itself is transactional in which case methods in A and B by default take part in the same transaction. Entities won't get detached until X completes.

Comment: Yeah, my hashcode and equals methods were problematic.  When I changed them to be based solely of the Entity's id, things worked fine.  Thanks, -